# SQL Query to Select Min and Max Values For Each Day Over a Period

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

I would like to `select` all the rows that contain either min or max datetime values for each `equipment_id`, for **every day** included in the period.

The code below selects the `min` and `max` datetime values for each `equipment_id` over the entire period. What can/should I change to reach desired select results?

**Note:** the values enclosed in braces in the code snippet represent dynamic values.

```
select *
from equipment
where created_at in (select min(created_at)
                     from equipment
                     where created_at >= {start_datetime} and created_at < {end_datetime}
                     group by equipment_id
                    ) or
      created_at in (select max(created_at)
                     from equipment
                     where created_at >= {start_datetime} and created_at < {end_datetime}
                     group by equipment_id
                    )
order by account, equipment_id, created_at asc;
```

Comment: Your code does not do what you think it does.  One equipment_id could have a `created_at` value that matches *another* equipment_id's max/min.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
select e.*
from (select e.*,
             min(e.created_at) over (partition by e.equipment_id, to_date(e.created_at)) as min_ca,
             max(e.created_at) over (partition by e.equipment_id, to_date(e.created_at)) as max_ca
      from equipment e
     ) e
where e.created_at in (min_ca, max_ca)
order by account, equipment_id, created_at asc;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, the results appear to be the same as the query I originally posted - i.e. I receive the min and max values for each `equipment_id` over the contents of the entire table rather than min and max values for every day within a period. Any suggestions regarding how to achieve that?

Comment: @Ari . . . Ah yes, the date needs to be added to the `partition by`.

Comment: A follow-up question, how would I limit the results to a specific, yet dynamically provided period? For example, let's say I want to `select` all the rows that contain either min or max datetime values for each equipment_id, for every day included between `2019-05-19 00:00:00` and `2019-05-21 00:00:00` only? How should I modify the above solution to achieve that?

Comment: @Ari . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: Yes, the answer returns the min and max rows (in accordance with timestamp) for **every** day in the target table. The original question, asked for those values **every** day for a specific **period**. I did not notice the discrepancy until I executed query on augmented data set.  I modified your answer as below.

Comment: `select m.* from (select m.*, min(m.created_at) over (partition by m.equipment_id, to_date(m.created_at)) as min_ca, max(m.created_at) over (partition by m.equipment_id, to_date(m.created_at)) as max_ca from measurements m where m.created_at >= '{start}' and m.created_at < '{end}') m where m.created_at in (min_ca, max_ca) order by account_guid, equipment_id, created_at asc`.

Comment: Note: `measurements m where m.created_at >= '{start}' and m.created_at < '{end}'`. This addition appears to fully answer the question. However, I did want to get your suggestions on the answer and hopefully have you amend your original answer accordingly.

Comment: @Ari . . . Just add a `where` clause to the subquery if you want to limit the query to a particular date range.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`to_date`](http://hadooptutorial.info/hive-date-functions/) to extract date from datetime value. Then, join on an aggregate query:

```
with agg as
  (select to_date(created_at) as created_date, 
          equipment_id,
          min(created_at) as min_created_at,
          max(created_at) as max_created_at
   from equipment
   group by to_date(created_at),
            equipment_id
  )

select e.*
from equipment e
left join agg
   on e.equipment_id = agg.equipment_id
   and to_date(e.created_at) = agg.created_date

where e.created_at in (agg.min_created_at, 
                       agg.max_created_at)
```